# php sql - select from table 1 when there is no entry in table 2 for a specific userID AND specific eventID

Tags: php, sql, select

I would like to show only the Event-Names - for which a specific (logged In user) has not already signed up.

There are two sql tables with the following rows:

> Table1 `Events`: `Event_ID (PK)` | `Event_Name`
>
> Table2 `Signups`: `Signup_ID (PK, AI)` | `Event_ID` | `User_ID`

The Event Signup works. BUT I am looking for a `SELECT` query where only the events are selected for which there is no corresponding signup for the specific (logged in) User?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: so you are going to get events from the table2 which the id of the person logged in doesn't have in  tablel2 or how is it?

Comment: That's what I tried: SELECT event_name.events, event_ID.events, signup_ID.signups, event_ID.signups, user_ID.signups FROM signups RIGHT JOIN events WHERE event_ID.events=event_ID.signups AND user_ID.signups='".$_SESSION["user_ID"]."'     ......But this returns the Evens for which the user has signed up. I would like to show the events where there is no signup (by this user)

Answer (score 0):

Then Try like this:-

```
select * from table_1 where Event_ID NOT IN (SELECT Event_ID FROM table_2 where Signup_ID = mysignupid )
```

This query is only a logic. Put values of your's accordingly. Post back if you have errors